# Не могу разобраться со спавном объектов в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сделал скрипт рандомного спавна объеков по клеткам, чтобы они не спавнились друг на друге, спавнились с редкостью.
Деревянная коробка и часы очень часто, каменная коробка, монеты и бомба реже чем деревянная коробка, красное зелье и зомби редко а зелёное зелье очень редко. Чтобы бомба и зомби не спавнилась рядом с персонажем.
Вот скрипт:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public Transform[] Spawn_Points; //Точки по которым спавнятся обьекты.
    public GameObject[] Objects; //Сами объекты.
    public bool[] IsFull; //Буллы для проверки есть ли на точке объект.
    public float spawnWait; //Время спавна
    public int Soft = 5; //Сколько ломающихся объектов на сцене
    public GameObject Bomb; //Ссылка бомбы
    public float Timer = 30; //Таймер
    public bool Exit = true; //Булл для проверки выхода из условия

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnWaves()); //Старт коррутины
    }      

    private void Update() {
        Timer -= Time.deltaTime; //Старт таймера
    }
    IEnumerator SpawnWaves()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            int randomSpawn = Random.Range(0, Spawn_Points.Length - 2); //Рандомный выбор точки спавна объекта
            int randomObject = Random.Range(0, 6); //Рандомный выбор спавна обычного объекта
            int randomRareObject = Random.Range(0, 3); //Рандомный выбор спавна редкого объекта
            int randomChance = Random.Range(0, 121); //Выбор рандомного числа шанса

            Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;

                if (randomObject == 0 || randomObject == 2 || randomObject == 3 || randomObject == 5 || randomObject == 6)
                {
                    Soft += 1; //При спавне ломающегося объекта прибавляем его здесь
                }   
                if (randomObject == 4)
                {
                    Bomb.GetComponent<Bomb_Script>().Respawn = true; //При спавне бомбы включаем отчет до взрыва
                }     

                if(Timer <= 10 && IsFull[randomSpawn] == true) { //Если таймер меньше 10 и IsFull точки спавна свободен
                    Instantiate(Objects[3], Spawn_Points[randomSpawn].position, spawnRotation); //Спавним часы
                    spawnWait = 3; //Возвращаем значение
                    Timer += 5; //К числу таймера плюсуем число которое дают часы
                    Exit = true; //Разрешаем проход дальше
                }
                else if(Timer <= 10) { //Если прошлое условие не верно и таймер меньше 10
                    Exit = false; //Запрещаем проход дальше
                    spawnWait = 0; //Ставим ожидание спавна на 0 чтобы быстрее заспавнить часы
                }
                if(randomChance <= 100 && IsFull[randomSpawn] == true && Exit == true) { //Если шанс равен или меньше 100, IsFull точки спавна свободен и проход доступен
                    if(randomObject == 2 && Soft >= 5) { //Если рандомный объект равен 2 и количество ломающихся объектов на сцене равно или больше 5
                        Instantiate(Objects[2], Spawn_Points[randomSpawn].position, spawnRotation);//Спавним каменную коробку
                        spawnWait = 3; //Возвращаем значение
                    }
                    else { //Если прошлое условие не верно
                    Instantiate(Objects[randomObject], Spawn_Points[randomSpawn].position, spawnRotation); //Спавним обычный рандомный объект
                        spawnWait = 3; //Возвращаем значение
                    }

                 }
                else if(randomChance >= 100 && randomChance <= 110 && IsFull[randomSpawn] == true) { //Если прошлое условие не верно, шанс равен или больше 100 но равен или меньше 110 и IsFull точки спавна свободен
                    Instantiate(Objects[7], Spawn_Points[randomSpawn].position, spawnRotation); //Спавн зелёного зелья
                    spawnWait = 3; //Возвращаем значение
                 }
                else if(randomChance >= 100 && IsFull[randomSpawn] == true) { //Если шанс равен или больше 100 и IsFull точки спавна свободен
                    Instantiate(Objects[randomRareObject], Spawn_Points[randomSpawn].position, spawnRotation); //Спавн редкого рандомного объекта
                    spawnWait = 3; //Возвращаем значение
                 } 
                else if(IsFull[randomSpawn] == false) //Если все выше перечисленные условия не равны и IsFull точки спавна не свободен
                {
                    spawnWait = 0; //Ставим ожидание спавна на 0 чтобы быстрее заспавнить объекты
                }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnWait);                                      
        }

    }
    
}
```

Осталось только сделать отдельный спавн зомби и бомбы вдалеке от игрока.
Может как-то оптимизировать.
Помогите как это сделать.

Comment: покажи скрины как это должно выглядеть, а то деревянная коробка, часы очень часто и т.д. непонятненько немного

Comment: ну а вообще тебе нужна матрица, в которой ты будешь смотреть занято или нет. при генерации объектов ты будешь пускать `Random.Range()` и в зависимости от шанса спавнить или нет. для шансов делаешь переменные по типу `float boxGenerationChance` и так для каждого типа объектов, ну а про бомбу и зомби, то во время выбора клетки ты смотришь, нет ли рядом в клетке твоего персонажа. Да, тут нужно самому посидеть подумать какие алгоритмы придумать, но а ты думал будет легко?

Comment: Вы можете редактировать свой вопрос, добавляйте ваш код прямо в текст вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class TileObject : MonoBehaviour // у предметов очевидно должен быть свой класс
{
    [SerializeField] private ObjectType _type;
    [SerializeField] private bool _isSoft = false;
    // относительный шанс (относительно других)
    // например A:6 к B:2, в A в твое чаще B
    [SerializeField] private int _spawnChange = 1;

    public ObjectType Type { get => _type; } // свойство позволяет читать (get), но не иметь право изменять (set)
    public bool IsSoft { get => _isSoft; }
    public int SpawnChange { get => _spawnChange; }
}
```

---

```
public enum ObjectType { BoxWood, BoxRock, PotionRed, PotionGreen, Clock, Coin, Zombie ,Bomb }

public class GameGrid : MonoBehaviour
{
    // поля внутренней кухни должны быть private
    // SerializeField делает поля видимыми в инспекторе
    [SerializeField] private float _sessionTime = 90f;
    [SerializeField] private float _spawnDelay = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private int _gridWidth = 10;
    [SerializeField] private int _gridHeight = 6;
    [SerializeField] private float _gridTileStep = 32;
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] private TileObject[] _objectTemplates; // все объекты
    private TileObject[,] _grid; // если это клетки то это должен быть двумерный массив (матрица) 
    private Dictionary<ObjectType, TileObject> _templates;
    private List<TileObject> _objects;
    private float _sessionBackTimer; // Timer чево... 
    private int _softCounter; // имя Soft не отображает функцию
    private IEnumerator _spawn;
    private IEnumerator _backTimer;

    private void Start ()
    {
        // для удобства создаём справочник объектов для поиска по их типу при необходимости _templates[ObjectType.Bomb]
        _templates = new Dictionary<ObjectType, TileObject>();
        foreach (TileObject template in _objectTemplates)
            _templates.Add(template.Type, template);
        _objects = new List<TileObject>();

        _grid = new TileObject[_gridWidth, _gridHeight];
        _sessionBackTimer = _sessionTime;
        _spawn = SpawnCoroutine(); // нужна ссылка на корутину, что бы потом её можно было остановить
        StartCoroutine(_spawn);
        _backTimer = BackTimerCoroutine();
        StartCoroutine(_backTimer);
    }

    private IEnumerator SpawnCoroutine ()
    {
        while (true) {
            if (GriidIsFull() == false) // одна функция, одна задача, есть ли пустые клетки
                SpawnObject(); // одна функция, одна задача, спавн
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(_spawnDelay);
        }
    }

    private void SpawnObject ()
    {
        TileObject Object = GetSpawnObject(); // одна задача, ролл спавнящегося предмета
        if (Object != null)
        {
            Vector2 Tile = GetFreeTile(); // одна задача, нахождение случайной свободной клетки
            TileObject NewObject = Instantiate(Object.gameObject, transform).GetComponent<TileObject>();
            NewObject.transform.localPosition = GetPositionOfTile(Tile);
            if (NewObject.IsSoft)
                _softCounter++;
            _grid[(int)Tile.x, (int)Tile.y] = NewObject;
            _objects.Add(NewObject);
        }
        else
            Debug.LogWarning("SpawnObject.Fail");
    }

    private TileObject GetSpawnObject ()
    {
        int ChanceSumm = 0; // сумма всех шансов
        foreach (var template in _templates)
            ChanceSumm += template.Value.SpawnChange;
        int Target = Random.Range(0, ChanceSumm); // случайное число из общей суммы
        foreach (var template in _templates)
        {
            Target -= template.Value.SpawnChange;
            if (Target <= 0)
                return template.Value; // на ком закончится и есть выпавший предмет
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Vector2 GetFreeTile ()
    {
        List<Vector2> FreeTiles = new List<Vector2>();
        for (int x = 0; x < _gridWidth; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < _gridHeight; y++)
                if (_grid[x, y] == null)
                    FreeTiles.Add(new Vector2(x, y));
        int Rnd = Random.Range(0, FreeTiles.Count);
        return FreeTiles[Rnd];
    }

    private bool GriidIsFull ()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < _gridWidth; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < _gridHeight; y++)
                if (_grid[x, y] == null)
                    return false;
        return true;
    }

    private Vector2 GetPositionOfTile (Vector2 tile)
    {
        Vector2 GridSize = new Vector2(_gridWidth-1, _gridHeight-1)*_gridTileStep;
        return -GridSize*0.5f+tile*_gridTileStep;
    }

    private IEnumerator BackTimerCoroutine ()
    {
        while (_sessionBackTimer > 0)
        {
            _sessionBackTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
        _sessionBackTimer = 0;
        TimeOut();
    }

    private void TimeOut ()
    {
        StopCoroutine(_spawn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Даёт вот такую ошибку: IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
GameGrid.GetFreeTile () (at Assets/Scripts/GameGrid.cs:164)
GameGrid.SpawnObject () (at Assets/Scripts/GameGrid.cs:132)
GameGrid+<SpawnCoroutine>d__14.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/GameGrid.cs:122)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at <b84561598fe94f54a0f4064cd1596cee>:0)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
GameGrid:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/GameGrid.cs:113)

Comment: `_gridWidth` вместоа `_gridHeight` в `for y`.

Comment: Всё равно ту же ошибку выдаёт. IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
GameGrid.GetFreeTile () (at Assets/Scripts/GameGrid.cs:164)
GameGrid.SpawnObject () (at Assets/Scripts/GameGrid.cs:132)
GameGrid+<SpawnCoroutine>d__14.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/GameGrid.cs:122)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at <b84561598fe94f54a0f4064cd1596cee>:0)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
GameGrid:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/GameGrid.cs:113)

Comment: Все изменил, ошибок нет, но объекты не спавнятся